# Removing first word in a string starting with digit using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am a novice to using regular expression. I have a string like this - `3G Wireless` I want to remove all the words that starting from digits so `3G Wireless` will become `Wireless`.

I have come up with this regex to do the job -

```
>>> re.sub("\S*\d\S*", "", "3g wireless")
' wireless'
```

It failing in cases like this -

```
>>> re.sub("\S*\d\S*", "", "RPG400")
''
```

I want to ignore the word only when it starts with a digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s*` considers any spaces before the actual digit at the beginning. `\b` checks for the first word.
Moreover, can use strip() afterward to remove any unneeded spaces in start and end of the remaining string.

```
re.sub(r'\s*\b(\d+\w*)', '', "3g wireless").strip()
# 'wireless'

re.sub(r'\s*\b(\d+\w*)', '', "RPG400").strip()
# 'RPG400'
```

Comment: First one outputs `g wireless`. I don't know how did you get `wireless`. Also it fails for any strings like `'any 3wireless'`.

Comment: @Austin. Yes, rightly said.  I had the wrong code posted here. It replaced only the digits but need to replace the whole word.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import re

s ='3g wireless'
print(re.sub(r'\b(\d+\w*)', '', s))
# wireless
```

- `\b` matches word boundary.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `\w*` matches zero or more alphabets or digits.

.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this `^\b(\d.*?)\b` ,
where `\b(\d.*?)\b` creates a boundary of words starting with digits, confined in its boundary,`^` specifies it to be at the start.

```
import re
text = '3G Wireless'
re.sub(r'^\b(\d.*?)\b','',text).strip()
# Wireless
```

[This would show it in working!](https://regex101.com/r/Gs3G52/1/)